# Login to Identity Server from inside a network

Tags: identityserver4

I have an IS4 install on a regular server on the WWW which is working perfectly for a number of client applications.

The client has a network and I need to install and application inside their local LAN which is not able to be addressable from the WWW.

Is it possible to login to the application inside the LAN via the IS4 instance and have the user return to the site inside the LAN?

Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. All IDP -> client interactions are done in the front-channel (i.e. in the context of the user's browser). The client app inside the customer's network will need to be able to connect to your IDP but not vice versa.